Adding a inverse relationship to already existing One-To-Many
My problem is: I already have a One-To-Many relationship. I just didn't implement the reverse property in the Many part, bc I didn't need it at the time. Now I do and here comes the problems.
Those are my two schemas and the respecting models in it (The names are placeholder bc I can't share the real entity names and so on):
actor SchemaV1_0_0: VersionedSchema {
    static let versionIdentifier = Schema.Version(1, 1, 0)
    static var models: [any PersistentModel.Type] {
        [EntityA.self, EntityB.self, SubEntityC.self, User.self]
    }
}

actor SchemaV1_1_0: VersionedSchema {
    static let versionIdentifier = Schema.Version(1, 1, 0)
    static var models: [any PersistentModel.Type] {
        [EntityA.self, EntityB.self, SubEntityC.self, User.self]
    }
}

extension SchemaV1_0_0 {
    @Model
    class EntityA: Hashable {
        let uuid: UUID = UUID()
        var start: EntityB?
        var end: EntityB?
        @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade)
        var subs: [SubEntityC] = []
        @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) var participants: [User] = []
        @Transient var lastHashCode: Int = 0
        var sentTimestamp: Date?
    }
    @Model
    class SubEntityC: Hashable {
        let uuid: UUID = UUID()
        var start: Date
        var end: Date?
        
        init(start: Date = Date()) {
            self.start = start
        }
    }
}

extension SchemaV1_1_0 {
    @Model
    class EntityA: Hashable {
        let uuid: UUID = UUID()
        var start: EntityB?
        var end: EntityB?
        var newProp: String
        @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \SubEntityC.entityA)
        var subs: [SubEntityC] = []
        @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) var participants: [User] = []
        @Transient var lastHashCode: Int = 0
        var sentTimestamp: Date?
    }
    @Model
    class SubEntityC: Hashable {
        let uuid: UUID = UUID()
        var start: Date
        var end: Date?
        var entityA: EntityA?
    }

}


This is my migration plan.
enum MigrationPlan: SchemaMigrationPlan {
    static var schemas: [any VersionedSchema.Type] {
        [
            SchemaV1_0_0.self,
            SchemaV1_1_0.self
        ]
    }
    
    static var stages: [MigrationStage] {
        [
            migrateV1_0_0toV1_1_0
        ]
    }
    
    static var migrateV1_0_0toV1_1_0: MigrationStage {
        MigrationStage
            .custom(
                fromVersion: SchemaV1_0_0.self,
                toVersion: SchemaV1_1_0.self
            ) { _ in } didMigrate: { context in
                if let entities = try? context.fetch(FetchDescriptor<SchemaV1_1_0.EntitiyA>()) {
                    for a in entities {
                        a.newProp = ""
                    }
                }
                try? context.save()
                print("Migrated from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0")
            }
    }
}

Now when I run my app, the ModelContainer init fails with the Exception: "The current model reference and the next model reference cannot be equal."
I don't get why and tried nearly anything, but can't get it to work. The problem is in V1.1.0 I added a new property which works as long as I don't add the ", inverse: \SubEntityC.entityA)" and the "var entityA: EntityA?" parts in the new Models. Point is, I need the inverse.
Also separating this to make 1.1.0 the new property and a 1.2.0 adding the inverse relationship doesn't work and errors with the same message.
Anyone have an idea why I get this error and how to fix it?
If you need additional information, let me know.
Any help is appreciated, I am spiralling over here...

My guess is that the reverse relationship property gets added automatically by SwiftData in your 1.0.0 version so therefore it doesn't see any change between the two versions. What happens if you don't use a custom migration?
